# Firebase import json adds all but then deletes everything

Tags: json, firebase

I'm trying to use the import json feature on Firebase. Specifically, I have a collection of data looking like:

```
{
    "1":"hello",
    "2":"world",
    "more":"nothingSoFar",
}
```

I want to overwrite the "more" section. So I click on "more", then hit "import json", and select my json file and click import. I see it adding all the nodes from my json file, but then the value of "more" switches to "null" and all the nodes get deleted from bottom to top like a collapsing accordion.

What's going on here? Is my json file too large?

Comment: Firebase accepts data in Base64 format only, also it has an upper limit of 10 MB for any `"Key":"Value"` pair, for more data to be uploaded, you need to make multiple `"Key":"Value"` pairs, and this way you can upload any file of any size.

Comment: @akhilesh1988: I'm not sure what you mean by "accepts base64 only". Firebase accept JSON data. One way to encode **binary** data into JSON is through base64 indeed. But regular JSON data is fine too.

Comment: "Is my json file too large?" Could be. How big is the JSON file that you're trying to import? Can you put the file you're trying to import somewhere for us to see? If not, this might be a case where support@firebase.com is a better way to help you.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, you are right, Firebase accepts any data in JSON format, by Base64 I was pointing to the same point that, any large file may probably be a media file or a binary file, so it should be converted to Base64 format in order to store it to the Fierbase.

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestions everyone. It looks like the file wasn't too large, because I manually added a few nodes under "more" using their graphical interface, and then clicked on "More" and imported. That worked, somehow. So for some reason it wasn't the size of the file that mattered. I'm not sure what happened.

Comment: i have the same thing when i try to import a second file. What did u do?